# How can I write branch-specific hooks in BZR?

Tags: bazaar, hook

In subversion, hooks are written on a per-repository basis. Each hook is written in a descriptive filename (e.g. pre-commit) in a folder named "hooks" at the root of the repository. According to the BZR docs, hooks are typically installed globally (e.g. in the ~/.bazaar/plugins/ directory).

Is it possible to create, say, a pre-commit hook that is committed to the branch and that runs without a user having to install a plugin?

I see in the docs and in some code discussions a reference to something called "branch hooks," which sounds promising.

I found this blog: http://schettino72.wordpress.com/2008/01/20/how-to-execute-tests-on-a-bazaar-pre-commit-hook/, which quotes:

> "plugins in bazaar are not project
>   specific. so you cant control in which
>   projects (branches) your plugin will
>   be applied (it will be applied to
>   all)."

which is less promising. The blog gives a workaround in that you write and install a plugin that calls hooks in your repository if they exist. Ideally, I want not to rely on users to install plugins for a really basic hook to run, namely a simple test. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your users have to install the plugin to activate your hook.

Answer (score 2):

You can use bazaar server and install hooks on them.

also You may find interested next links:

http://people.samba.org/bzr/jelmer/bzr-shell-hooks/trunk/

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~stianse/%2Bjunk/bzr-shell-hooks/

Answer (score 2):

I did some research into this and found motivation behind the lack of branch-specific hooks in distributed revision control systems. I had compared to Subversion, a centralized RCS, as an example of the desired feature.

GIT and Mercurial are distributed RCSs (like Bazaar) that have tools for hooks, including different approaches to branch-specific hooks and global hooks. Regardless, the hooks are not revision controlled and they require the user of the branch to enable them due to the security risk. In the [Mercurial documentation on hooks](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html), under the section titled "Hooks and security," it says:

> In Mercurial, hooks are not revision
>   controlled, and do not propagate when
>   you clone, or pull from, a repository.
>   The reason for this is simple: a hook
>   is a completely arbitrary piece of
>   executable code. It runs under your
>   user identity, with your privilege
>   level, on your machine.
>
> It would be extremely reckless for any
>   distributed revision control system to
>   implement revision-controlled hooks,
>   as this would offer an easily
>   exploitable way to subvert the
>   accounts of users of the revision
>   control system.

In a centralized RCS, like Subversion, the hooks are run on the repository server, so user permissions and server-setup restrict the impact of a damaging hook script. In a distributed RCS, the hooks are typically run on the user's local machine, which is risky.

As vitaly.v.ch mentions, a Bazaar server could be setup to run hooks when pushed to and pulled from. But then a pre-commit hook doesn't make sense, since the commits happen on the user's machine. It would then be more like a pre-push hook.

Bazaar has all the needed functionality for hooks, but individual user configuration is required to install and enable them due to the security risk they pose.